# How can I send data from a TCP Python server to a client and vice-versa?

Tags: python, xml, json, serialization, client-server

I am writing a simple chat application in Python. As part of that, I was wondering what is the best method to send custom objects from the server to the client. I believe there are three methods that are widely used:

1. XML File, though I guess that's become obsolete now...
2. JSON document
3. Pickling and unpickling

Is there any other method that can be used which beats the above mentioned? If not, which is the best method among the three?

Comment: For chat? I would say `json`. But it ultimately boils down to *whatever you are more comfortable with*.

Comment: Thank you. I have been using pickling though. But, I am a little confused as to how the server and the client can send different forms of data by just pickling an object - somehow makes the code look inefficient. For eg. if the server wants the client to let him know that a requested chat recipient is not online, I would have to create a different class for that, create an object of that message and send the pickled object. I feel there's something that I am doing completely wrong.

Comment: The check that you are applying, should *always* be done. Follow certain **procedure** or steps of communication. e.g. 1. Do a server-client *handshake*. 2. Verify contacting client. 3. Check if the client's request is valid. 4. If request is valid, proceed accordingly.

Comment: If you ever want to have a client on e.g. your phone (then written in objective-c, java, ...) you better use an open encoding standard like JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use pickle. Using pickle in a client-server application would mean to unpickle data from untrusted sources. If you look at the [pickle documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle), there's a big red warning about that on top of the page. Basically, pickle is unsecure, and by unpickling arbitrary pickled data you risk allowing anyone to run custom code on your server and clients.

Choose a data exchange format you're comfortable with, doesn't really matter if it's xml, json, a custom protocol, etc... But pickle isn't designed for data exchange.

Comment: If you want to use JSON, the simplest way to implement what you need is through an HTTP server, like [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/).